# Coordinator Layout - unwanted animation on layout shrink

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

In my application i have `CoordinatorLayout` with nested custom view, which has custom `MoveUpwardBehavior`. When `Snackbar` appears, I want this view to be pushed over it and it works.

The problem is, that `CoordinatorLayout` is nested in `RelativeLayout` which has flag `animateLayoutChanges=true`. When `RelativeLayout` animates its views, `CoordinatorLayout` shrinks a bit (vertically). It causes, that mentioned custom view also moves, but i want to make it stick to its position. Any thoughts, how I can accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `CoordinatorLayout` to be top-level layout instead of wrapping it inside another parent. The animation and displacement of the views during layout animation is totally normal. You may want to tweak your `MoveUpwardBehavior` to get the target view to keep the intended behavior, in case that your custom view is not direct descendant of `CoordinatorLayout`.